# What is MaheshsMacBookPro-Bluet on /dev in MacOS

Tags: macos, security

## Background

I am trying to secure my MacMini.

```
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 11.4
BuildVersion:   20F71
```

## Issue

I listed the devices in /dev and found out about tty.MaheshsMacBookPro-Bluet. But I am unsure what this device does and I am unable to find anything on the web.

```
bash-3.2$ ls -la /dev | grep MaheshsMacBookPro-Bluet
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     wheel           22,   5  4 Jul 20:17 cu.MaheshsMacBookPro-Bluet
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     wheel           22,   4  4 Jul 20:17 tty.MaheshsMacBookPro-Bluet
```

Furthermore, accessing the device says resource busy:

```
cat: /dev/tty.MaheshsMacBookPro-Bluet: Resource busy
bash-3.2$ echo 1 > /dev/tty.MaheshsMacBookPro-Bluet
bash: /dev/tty.MaheshsMacBookPro-Bluet: Resource busy
```

How can I get more information about this tty based device or connection? Or any relevant information.

Comment: Do you have any other devices matching `*Blue*`?

Comment: Just this.
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     wheel           22,   1  4 Jul 20:17 cu.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port
crw-rw-rw-   1 root     wheel           22,   0  4 Jul 20:17 tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port

Comment: It's a Bluetooth connection to Mahesh's MacBook Pro from a year ago.  Is that not you?

Comment: @MarcWilson This device is not used frequently. It was off for a while and I was just setting up things to make it useful. So there is no way it should have been paired with any other device, and I do not have any device named as such. And the device is functional as it seems. I intend to get deep insights to the issue.